# Accessing AngularJS UI-Select selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ui-select

Currently i have multiple dropdown directives that share the same array of dropdown values. When I make a selection, it'll update the rest of the dropdown selected value as well how do I go about having a unique selection for the rest of my dropdowns.

My current work around would be setting `ng-model="ctrl.ngModel"` however I will not be able to access the dropdown selected value.

dropdown.html

```
<div>
  <ui-select name='' ng-model="ctrl.ngModel.selected" theme="bootstrap" class='expiry admin-expiry'
    append-to-body='true'
    reset-search-input='true'
    on-select="ctrl.update()">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="choice in ctrl.choices | filter: $select.search"
      position='down'>
      <span ng-bind-html="ctrl.trustAsHtml(choice.value)"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
  function ColDropdownDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        choices: '='
      },
      controller: ['FxoUtils', function(_) {
        var ctrl = this;
        this.trustAsHtml = function(value) {
          return _.trustAsHtml(value);
        };

        this.update = function() {
          console.log(ctrl.ngModel.selected);
        };
      }],
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'js/fxo/admin/thresholdconfig/common/common.col.dropdown.html'
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy your choices into an array of three unique copies of your choices. Then you could access these choices in your template like: `choice in ctrl.choicesArr[0]` or `[1]` or `[2]`. You'll also want to use three different `ng-model`s to represent the selected value of your three dropdowns.

```
function ColDropdownDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            choices: '='
        },
        controller: ['FxoUtils', function(_) {
            var ctrl = this;
            this.choicesArr = [
                angular.copy(this.choices),
                angular.copy(this.choices),
                angular.copy(this.choices),
            ];
            this.trustAsHtml = function(value) {
                return _.trustAsHtml(value);
            };

            this.update = function() {
                console.log(ctrl.ngModel.selected);
            };
        }],
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'js/fxo/admin/thresholdconfig/common/common.col.dropdown.html'
    };
}
```